# ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: No space left on device

Tags: java

I am getting the following error when running the `report(JReport)` from java my application.

> Caused by: ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
>   Please help to get the space issue resolved.

**Complete stacktrace:**

```
jet.server.api.RptServerException: To PDF - Status: Error!
The following error occurred while running the report:
   jet.export.ExpException: Export report to PDF format error.
     Export report to PDF format error.
    jet.export.ExpException: Export report to PDF format error.
        at jet.export.pdf.ExportToPDF.exportToFile(QOIV:318)
        at jet.export.ExportEngineForViewer.exportToPDFFile(QOIV:359)
        at jet.bean.JREngine.exportToPDF(QOIV:19894)
        at jet.bean.JRSetEngine$ReportEngineAPIImpl.exportToPDF(QOIV:5275)
        at jet.server.jrc.engine.JRReportEngine.exportToPdf(QOIV:521)
        at jet.server.schedule.jrtasks.ReportSheetRunner.exportToPdf(QOIV:1524)
        at jet.server.schedule.jrtasks.ReportSheetRunner.exportToPdf(QOIV:1482)
        at jet.server.schedule.jrtasks.ReportSheetRunner.exportToDisk(QOIV:976)
        at jet.server.schedule.jrtasks.ReportSheetRunner.export(QOIV:759)
        at jet.server.schedule.jrtasks.ReportSheetRunner.runReport(QOIV:228)
        at jet.server.schedule.jrtasks.ReportSheetRunner.run(QOIV:295)
        at jet.server.schedule.jrtasks.RunRptTask._runReport(QOIV:1374)
        at jet.server.schedule.jrtasks.RunRptTask.runingReport(QOIV:1279)
        at jet.server.schedule.jrtasks.RunRptTask.runReport(QOIV:1202)
        at jet.server.jrc.JRTaskManager.runReport(QOIV:592)
        at jet.server.jrserver.JRRptServer.runReport(QOIV:1154)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.clsReportBeanHelper.strGenerateReport(clsReportBeanHelper.java:323)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.clsReportEJB.runBatchJob(clsReportEJB.java:523)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.clsReportEJB.checkBatchJob(clsReportEJB.java:452)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.ReportEJB_n1e5y0_EOImpl.checkBatchJob(ReportEJB_n1e5y0_EOImpl.java:45)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.ReportEJB_n1e5y0_EOImpl_CBV.checkBatchJob(Unknown Source)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.clsStartupEJB.checkBatchJob(clsStartupEJB.java:162)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.StartupEJB_jb05li_EOImpl.checkBatchJob(StartupEJB_jb05li_EOImpl.java:45)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.StartupEJB_jb05li_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:491)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ReplicaAwareServerRef.invoke(ReplicaAwareServerRef.java:120)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:434)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:147)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:429)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicExecuteRequest.execute(BasicExecuteRequest.java:35)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:224)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
    Caused by: ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
            at jet.server.jrc.JRTaskManager.runReport(QOIV:600)
        at jet.server.jrserver.JRRptServer.runReport(QOIV:1154)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.clsReportBeanHelper.strGenerateReport(clsReportBeanHelper.java:323)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.clsReportEJB.runBatchJob(clsReportEJB.java:523)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.clsReportEJB.checkBatchJob(clsReportEJB.java:452)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.ReportEJB_n1e5y0_EOImpl.checkBatchJob(ReportEJB_n1e5y0_EOImpl.java:45)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.ReportEJB_n1e5y0_EOImpl_CBV.checkBatchJob(Unknown Source)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.clsStartupEJB.checkBatchJob(clsStartupEJB.java:162)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.StartupEJB_jb05li_EOImpl.checkBatchJob(StartupEJB_jb05li_EOImpl.java:45)
        at com.axacr.rams.reports.sb.StartupEJB_jb05li_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:491)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ReplicaAwareServerRef.invoke(ReplicaAwareServerRef.java:120)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:434)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManage"
```

Comment: paste some code not only stack trace and also use formatting style properly.

Comment: I don't know what you think we can do. Your disk is full.

Comment: disk is having space please find below.

Comment: /dev/mapper/rootvg-rootvol
                      4.9G  600M  4.1G  13% /
/dev/mapper/rootvg-homevol
                      3.9G  2.0G  1.8G  53% /home
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp
                      2.0G   68M  1.8G   4% /tmp
/dev/mapper/rootvg-varvol
                      2.0G  1.9G   32M  99% /var
/dev/mapper/rootvg-usrvol
                      3.9G  2.0G  1.8G  53% /usr
/dev/mapper/rootvg-optvol
                      2.0G  1.2G  724M  62% /opt
/dev/sda1              99M   17M   78M  18% /boot
tmpfs                 1.2G     0  1.2G   0% /dev/shm